# How to pass variable from client side to the server side to set the webchartcontol width

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

My problem is the webchartcontrol for devexpress library only accept the width in px not relative and i want to set the width recording to it's parent div.

I tried a lot of thing but due to lack of coding and i am beginner in asp.net. I do not know the correct way to pass the width of the div to the server side and then set the width of the chart control on page load , i tried to set hidden field value and call from JavaScript but it didn't work

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">




    <div id="demo">

        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="500" runat="server"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

           document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = 1000;
        </script>





        <dx:WebChartControl ID="Chart" runat="server" OnCustomCallback="Chart_CustomCallback" CrosshairEnabled="True" Height="200px" Width="300px">


        </dx:WebChartControl>




    </div>

</asp:Content>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                  Load_Live_Trend(Chart);
                Chart.Width = new Unit(Convert.ToInt32(Hidden1));

            }



        }
```

Comment: You should re-format code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with v18.2, WebChartControl supports the client-side [SetChartSize](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientWebChartControl.SetChartSize(width-height)) method that sends a callback and render the chart with a new size (see the [ASPxClientWebChartControl](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientWebChartControl) API). See also: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-resize-a-chart-according-to-the-actual-size-of-a-web-browsers-window-e252.